# Finding independent tags right next to each other in python scraping

Tags: python, html, python-3.x

I am trying to scrape a Wikipedia page. And facing a simple issue and not able to find the solution. There are 2 tags of th and td next to each other. Also, both of them are independent. I want to get the text of the 1 tag based on the value of the other tag (independent to each other).

Here is an example:

```
<th scope="row" style="white-space:nowrap;padding-right:0.65em;">Budget</th>
<td style="line-height:1.3em;">$200 million<sup id="cite_ref-3" class="reference"><a href="#cite_note-3">[3]</a></sup></td>
```

I want to get the value of 'td' tag (which is $200 million), if the 'th' tag text is 'Budget'. And remember the only correspondence is 'right next to each other'.

Comment: post the url will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''<th scope="row" style="white-space:nowrap;padding-right:0.65em;">Budget</th>
<td style="line-height:1.3em;">$200 million<sup id="cite_ref-3" class="reference"><a href="#cite_note-3">[3]</a></sup></td>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
td_text = soup.find(lambda tag: tag.name=='td' and 'Budget' in tag.parent.text).text
print(td_text)
```

out:

```
$200 million[3]
```